# Writing PostgreSQL Functions in C++

Tags: c++, postgresql

I have some problem writing postgres functions in C++ while following the guides for C: [C-Language Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xfunc-c.html). I found that most postgres functions are written in C instead C++, but I have to use a lib that is written in C++, so I chose C++. My question is, is there anything to notice when writing in C++? It's common to write makefiles using pgxs, so how should I write the makefile to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: One thing to think about is that you might have to mark your C++ function as `extern "C"`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Alas, it's nowhere near that easy. palloc() complicates things, c++ exception handling doesn't play well with C without very defensive coding at all C/C++ interface points, and Pg's longjmp based error handling throws a major spanner into the works.

Comment: To paraphrase Linus: c++ was only created to attract idiots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can avoid doing it, do so. PostgreSQL doesn't mix especially well with C++. It's possible, <strike>as shown by PostGIS</strike>, but it's not overly fun.

If you can, write or generate a pure C wrapper to your C++ library and use that wrapper to interact with the library. That won't be practical if it's heavily template based (eg: boost) or uses other more advanced C++ features, but works well if it's just C-with-objects style code. SWIG can help generate wrappers for you.

If you'd prefer to avoid the wrapper approach or if your library is a bit too complex, too exception-reliant, etc for that then you should [read this PostgreSQL manual entry](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP).

Search the PostgreSQL mailing list for more discussion on this topic.