# using C++ functions in PostreSQL

Tags: c++, postgresql, c++17

I'm trying out the code in this blog about [C++14 and postgres](https://www.openscg.com/2017/03/c14-and-postgres/) to test the feasibility of the well-known problem of [Writing PostgreSQL Functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500954) (with PostgreSQL 10.1, Ubuntu 16.04).

The code (`extension.cpp`) seems simple enough:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    #include <postgres.h>    //all C headers and macros go inside extern "C"
    #include <utils/rel.h>
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
}

#include<vector>           //C++ headers go outside

extern "C" {
    int sumofall() {        //wrap the C++ function inside the extern "C" block
        auto sum_of_all = 0;
        std::vector<int> arr {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        for (auto& i : arr)
            sum_of_all += i;
        return sum_of_all;
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but the problem is that the C++ function cannot be found or called from PostgreSQL with the commands as follows:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -g3 -O0 -I$(pg_config --includedir-server) extension.cpp
g++ -shared -o my-extension.so extension.o

sudo cp my-extension.so $(pg_config --pkglibdir)

psql -U postgres -h localhost $(whoami) -c "
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
   sumofall() RETURNS integer AS 'my-extension' 
LANGUAGE C STRICT;"
```

Postgres returns an error:

> ERROR:  could not find function information for function "sumofall"
> HINT:  SQL-callable functions need an accompanying
> PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(funcname).

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: The error message you get seems clear enough. Have you tried its hint?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I haven't written a PostreSQL C or C++ function before. This is the first allegedly working example of postgres function in C++ that I can find. Just wanted to check if I'm missing something in replicating it, or the example itself is not good.

Comment: @tinlyx did you make it work? I have the same problem with using C++ Code inside a PostgreSQL C language extension.

Comment: @tinlyx so how did it go - we wonder. Could you also mark the correct answer if there's any or perhaps write an answer yourself now that you know it?

Answer (score 3):

Read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/xfunc-c.html#id-1.8.3.12.7):

> The version-1 calling convention relies on macros to suppress most of the complexity of passing arguments and results. The C declaration of a version-1 function is always:
>
> ```
> Datum funcname(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
> ```
>
> In addition, the macro call:
>
> ```
> PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(funcname);
> ```
>
> must appear in the same source file. (Conventionally, it's written just before the function itself.)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fundamental observation of @Laurenz, you should also provide a .control file to install the extension and inform postgresql on how use it. 
Here I can show a .control file I've at hand now.

```
# file: tm_ext.control :
comment = 'Comments....'
default_version = '0.0.1'
directory = 'extension' # /usr/share/postgresql/{pg_ver}/extension/
module_pathname = '$libdir/tm_ext'
relocatable = false
schema = tm_ext
```

Then you have to declare functions pointing to the sharedlib like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tm_ext.doit([args..]) RETURNS integer
     AS '$libdir/tm_ext', 'doit'
     LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

Read the doc [extend-extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/extend-extensions.html)