# How to write a c++ extension for postgres?

Tags: c++, postgresql, extension-methods

I find something in this link [using C++ functions in PostreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892087/using-c-functions-in-postresql), but the blog it gives [C++14 and postgres](https://www.openscg.com/2017/03/c14-and-postgres/)  can't visit. I add a util.cpp and util.h for a c extension and I try to invoke the func `Print()`
util.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    void Print();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

util.cpp

```
#include "util.h"
#include <vector>
// #include <cstring>
#include <string>
extern "C"
{
#include <postgres.h>
}

void Print()
{
    std::string s = "anc";
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        elog(INFO, "vec %d", v[i]);
    }
    elog(INFO, "string %s:", s);
    elog(INFO, "Print");
}
```

I have added the PG_CXXFLAGEs and PG_CPPFLAGS in the makefile:

```
PG_CXXFLAGS      = -std=gnu++17 -libstdc++
PG_CPPFLAGS      = -std=gnu++17 -libstdc++
```

After I make install the extension, and I execute a sql, but I get:

```
could not load library "/data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so": /data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0
```

I hope to solve this problem, need a doc to add cpp files for my extension or about how to modify the Makefile correctly.

Comment: The blog post that you point to and won't load has been archived on the Way back machine and can be found here, if it helps: https://web.archive.org/web/20170703160924/https://www.openscg.com/2017/03/c14-and-postgres/

Comment: Did you set Postgres to path?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the library. But have seen this type of error before.

Lets look at what the error is telling you.

could not load library "/data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so": /data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so: undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0

There are two things that stick out.
(1) where is the m3v.so ? Is it relative to your run path? Do you need to compile your program to add it to your path?
Example flags maybe
-Wl,-rpath,path/to/lib -Lpath/to/lib -l3v  ??
-Wl,-rpath,path/to/lib -Lpath/to/lib -m3v  ??

Maybe you can add m3v.so to your profile path so that it work?

(2) Also it is telling that you have a undefined symbol.
This literally means you have a definition in a header that is not define.

For example:

```
//somelib.hpp

void someFunc();



//main.cpp

#include "somelib.hpp"

int main() {
someFunc();
return 0;
}
```

Clearly will not work because someFunc is undefined.

Does your library need to be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

```
could not load library "/data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so": /data/lib/postgresql/m3v.so:
```

You might need to:

(a)Check if the library exists on the path or/and

(b)Check if the library path is specified correctly in your Makefile

```
undefined symbol: __gxx_personality_v0
```

This might mean that there might be a function or symbol that in your file but it is undefined.Check in your library if the missing symbol is there or check the correct spelling.